# Cannot import GPG keys via apt-key

Tags: apt, ppa, gnupg, mono, keyserver

I'm trying to install mono on my Ubuntu 20.04 server.

I followed the official install instructions about `Mono` on [Download](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/)

When executing:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
```

the following error is raised:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.l2rhGqvMmi/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No such file or directory
```

In similar questions, I saw that more insights could be drawn from running strace. So here is the output for strace. I had to cut some of the intermediate output, to match the post character limit:

```
execve("/usr/bin/apt-key", ["apt-key", "adv", "--keyserver", "hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80", "--recv-keys", "3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38"...], 0x7ffc2afa5c18 /* 13 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55e6a789c000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffc1557cd50) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=63853, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 63853, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1cd10ad000
close(3)                                = 0
[...]
read(3, "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-ke"..., 128) = 55
read(3, "", 128)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 19223
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19223, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 19223
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.nBHDrgCJ0q/pubring.gpg", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 11
close(1)                                = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1cd10ac850) = 19224
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 19224
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19224, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 19224
dup2(11, 1)                             = 1
close(11)                               = 0
wait4(-1, 0x7ffc1557bfac, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.nBHDrgCJ0q/pubring.gpg", R_OK) = 0
stat("/usr/local/sbin/cp", 0x7ffc1557c600) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/cp", 0x7ffc1557c600) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/cp", 0x7ffc1557c600)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/cp", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=153976, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1cd10ac850) = 19225
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 19225
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19225, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 19225
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1cd10ac850) = 19226
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.nBHDrgCJ0q/"..., 128) = 41
read(3, "", 128)                        = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19226, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0
close(3)                                = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 19226
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1cd10ac850) = 19229
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.nBHDrgCJ0q/"..., 128) = 44
read(3, "", 128)                        = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19229, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0
close(3)                                = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 19229
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.nBHDrgCJ0q/gpg.1.sh", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 11
close(1)                                = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "#!/bin/sh\nexec sh '/tmp/apt-key-"..., 122) = 122
dup2(11, 1)                             = 1
close(11)                               = 0
write(1, "Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome."..., 147Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.nBHDrgCJ0q/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
) = 147
stat("/usr/local/sbin/sh", 0x7ffc1557c700) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/sh", 0x7ffc1557c700) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/sh", 0x7ffc1557c700)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/sh", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=129816, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1cd10ac850) = 19232
wait4(-1, gpg: keyserver receive failed: No such file or directory
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 2}], 0, NULL) = 19232
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19232, si_uid=0, si_status=2, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 19232
wait4(-1, 0x7ffc1557c59c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
stat("/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.nBHDrgCJ0q/aptwarnings.log", 0x7ffc1557c4d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "gpgconf", X_OK)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/sbin/gpgconf", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/bin/gpgconf", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/sbin/gpgconf", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/gpgconf", X_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 11
close(1)                                = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(2, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 12
close(2)                                = 0
fcntl(12, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(1, 2)                              = 2
stat("/usr/local/sbin/gpgconf", 0x7ffc1557c660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/gpgconf", 0x7ffc1557c660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/gpgconf", 0x7ffc1557c660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/gpgconf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=178848, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1cd10ac850) = 19237
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 19237
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19237, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 19237
dup2(11, 1)                             = 1
close(11)                               = 0
dup2(12, 2)                             = 2
close(12)                               = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1cd10ac850) = 19242
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 19242
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19242, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 19242
wait4(-1, 0x7ffc1557c83c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
exit_group(2)                           = ?
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

I would appreciate any help.
If I should provide additional info, I'm happy to do so.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved the problem.

`apt-key adv`, basically tells GnuPG to download the keys from the server.
First, I thought the keys didn't exist, since a search via the [keyserver.ubuntu.com](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/) web site turned out negative.
But when prepending `0x` to the key, it is found. The [Key not found on keyserver or keyserver not accessible](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/18927) issue is known.

Then I directly called `gpg` to download the keys via:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
```

That also failed, with the same error message. I then found an [Arch Linux BBS thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=252494), which described the same issue. Their solution was to fix the `/etc/resolve.conf` file. And indeed, this also helped me (apparently my `systemd-resolved.service` was failing).

Would have been much easier, if the error message was more helpful. But, ok. I guess it's my fault for not setting up DNS properly.